# How is the GENERATED_ID created in a custom oData Service to feed an Analytical Table?

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap

In a custom oData Service I need an Entity that will feed an analytical Table in sapui5. The table should show the sum of the `VBELN` positions.

The Entity collects already the `VBELN` positions and all the needed supplementary attributes and the data can be displayed in sapui5 in a Responsive Table.

Now this Table has been changed to an analytical table and the annotations for aggregation, dimensions and measures were done in the `DEFINE` method of the `MPC_EXT` class.

In `SEGW` a mapping was done between the Entity Set and the Structure used in the back-end to collect the data.

In the `DPC_EXT` class, the method `if_sadl_gw_query_control~SET_QUERY_OPTIONS` defines the SUM columns, and the method `GET_ENTITY` calls `get_keys_from_analytical_id`.

But something seems to be missing. In my front-end application I receive many copies of the very same record and when looking at the data I can see that the `GENERATED_ID` is empty.

How do I populate the `GENERATED_ID` in a custom oData Service?

I followed these documentations:

- https://archive.sap.com/kmuuid2/b0405b7f-c1d2-3110-79bd-ce64f64ea6b7/How%20to%20Use%20OData%20Analytics%20in%20SADL-Based%20Services.pdf
- https://blogs.sap.com/2018/01/12/fiori-elements-analytical-table-with-sadl/

ABAP code:

```
method DEFINE.
  DATA(lo_entity_type) = model->get_entity_type( 'Overview' ).
  lo_entity_type->set_semantic(
      /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_semantic_value-query-aggregate ).

  DATA(lo_property) = lo_entity_type->get_property( 'Auftraggeber' ).
  DATA(lo_annotation) = lo_property->/iwbep/if_mgw_odata_annotatabl~create_annotation( 
      /iwbep/if_mgw_med_odata_types=>gc_sap_namespace ).
  lo_annotation->add( 
      iv_key   = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_key-aggregation_role
      iv_value = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_value-dimension-dimension ).


  lo_property = lo_entity_type->get_property( 'Verkaufsbeleg' ).
  lo_annotation->add( 
      iv_key   = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_key-aggregation_role
      iv_value = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_value-dimension-dimension ).

  lo_property = lo_entity_type->get_property( 'Position' ).
  lo_annotation->add( 
      iv_key   = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_key-aggregation_role
      iv_value = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_value-dimension-dimension ).

  lo_property = lo_entity_type->get_property( 'Menge' ).
  lo_annotation->add( 
      iv_key   = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_key-aggregation_role
      iv_value = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_value-measure-measure ).

  lo_property = lo_entity_type->get_property( 'Umsatz' ).
  lo_annotation->add( 
      iv_key   = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_key-aggregation_role
      iv_value = /iwbep/if_ana_odata_types=>gcs_ana_odata_annotation_value-measure-measure ).
endmethod.      


method IF_SADL_GW_QUERY_CONTROL~SET_QUERY_OPTIONS.
  io_query_options->set_aggregation( VALUE #(
  ( element = 'MENGE'  alias = 'MENGE'  type = if_sadl_gw_query_options=>co_aggregation_type-sum )
  ( element = 'UMSATZ' alias = 'UMSATZ' type = if_sadl_gw_query_options=>co_aggregation_type-sum )
  ) ).
endmethod.      

method /IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~GET_ENTITY.
  if_sadl_gw_dpc_util~get_dpc( )->get_keys_from_analytical_id(
      EXPORTING io_tech_request_context = io_tech_request_context
      IMPORTING et_keys = DATA(lt_keys) ).
endmethod.
```

Comment: The GENERATED_ID should be generated by SADL .

Comment: I agree with that, but it's a custom oData Service, so how is the GENERATED_ID added to my custom entityset? I suppose that I have to implement this on my own? But how to retrieve the ID?

Comment: a custom oData service? you mean you implement the data retrieval logic by yourself instead of by SADL?

Comment: yes the data for the entityset is retrieved by custom code, selects on different tables etc