# Analytic Smart Table and OData Service

Tags: odata, sapui5, analytics, sap-fiori

I'm trying to implement a Smart Analytical Table with the use of OData Services. I understand what needs to be done on the frontend side (it's a custom Fiori App) and what annotations should be in place.

The only thing that confuses me is the backend implementation. I know that the service can be prepared using SADL framework, but I need to include a complex custom logic behind that. I have a lot of table relations and non-trival filter logic.

Is it possible to write non-SADL OData Service with the custom ABAP implementation for analytical purposes? SADL is handling a lot of things like aggregations, generated ids, etc. I'm not sure what's the best approach in such a case. Maybe there is a possibility to add custom code to generated sadl classes.

I need to provide a complex analytical table with nested groups, sums and also complex filtering. What are your experiences? What is your recommendation upon this Analytical Table?

Answer (score 0):

from my experience SADL should only be used for simple entity constallations. For example when all your entities represent the tables exactly. For all other scenarios I would always prefer own OData Services with the crud operations implemented over the service classes. If you haven't implemented an Code based Odata service see this blog post https://blogs.sap.com/2016/05/31/odata-service-development-with-sap-gateway-code-based-service-development/

Comment: For completion reason here is a link to a blog post about the different ways of providing an Odata service https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/12/odata-service-development-options/

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your response. I'm familiar with writing custom Services, but the problem is more complex here. Analytical Service requires a special GENERATED_ID property (mainly for the grouping purposes) and it's maintained automatically by SADL. I wasn't able to re-create a proper one manually. I'm just wondering if it is even possible.

It's also related to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838791/how-is-the-generated-id-created-in-a-custom-odata-service-to-feed-an-analytical